# Is there a workaround to empty event queue in separate thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, events, pygame, ipython

I used a separate thread to call `pygame.event.get()` for ages on Ubuntu without any problem. However MacOS throws an exception `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'nextEventMatchingMask should only be called from the Main Thread!'` ; and Windows reports the window to be `(Not answering)` after a few seconds of normal execution, which I assume to have the same explanation, meaning that Linux is tolerant to this software design unlike other OSes.

Is there any workaround to keep emptying the event queue in a separate thread, or does it basically mean that pygame 1.9.1 on python 2.7 cannot work that way at all?

I know GUI events are usually handled in main thread, but my Python lib is intended to be used with ipython. By design, the main thread, i.e. the user's ipython cells might be executing no operation or CPU-greedy loops, thus it can't take care of `pygame.event.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to post events from other thread, but the event queue has to be handled in the main thread. See the documentation of [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html):

> [...] The event subsystem should be called from the main thread. [...]

However, if you read on

> [...] If you want to post events into the queue from other threads, please use the `pygame.fasteventpygame` module for interacting with events and queues module. [...]

See [`pygame.fastevent`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/fastevent.html#module-pygame.fastevent) module:

> `pygame.fastevent` is a wrapper for Bob Pendleton's *fastevent* library. It provides fast events for use in multithreaded environments.